# Override angular material default styling for sorting table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am pretty new to angular material. My requirement is: Show the sorting icons even if you are not hovering over the table header. Currently I see the icon appears only when you hover over the table. 
I don't find any option related to that in the material docs: https://material.angular.io/components/sort/overview .

Answer (score 0):

```
::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-arrow {
opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself: what does this do if I didn't read the question completely/or misunderstood it? Please add context. (From Review).